# How do I save all my Intellij code style config, plugin config, and remote run config in one .idea file?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

**Does anyone want to share their Intellij xml workspace config?**

I'm trying to set up a global configuration file for all the intellij project configurations shared across workspaces, including Google code style guide.

1. The code style according to Google code style guide as defined in Editor > Code Style.
2. The plugins I have installed for Intellij should be saved in the IDEA global configuration to be shared.
3. The remote run configurations. I need to run the code in ssh (i.e. ssh -A myhost.host.com /run/this/command/ -with -these -args) and I want to configure that in the Intellij global configurations.
4. Finally, I want to be able to export this all in one IDEA file that others can download.

Comment: Check the settings repository. There you can save your settings in your own repository

Comment: What settings repository? Will the workspace xml have all the plugins etc built in too?

Comment: All settings will be saved in there. You just have to reinstall the plugins. Just search for intellij settings repository.

Comment: Search where? in preferences?

Comment: In Google. You will get to the jetbrains webpage and find a documentation how to setup. But yes they are located in the preferences

Comment: @bycfly See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839. Everything except plugins configuration can be stored and shared with the project. You can't store everything in a single file, it would be a set of files under `.idea` directory.